# Blueprint CSS - Link showing both URL and text

Tags: blueprint-css

I'm using Blueprint as my CSS framework in my rails project. But currently I'm having a problem as when I created a link,
it shows both the link and display text in the web page

Ex : say I have
'[go to google](http://www.google.com)'

in my web page (view) it shows both 
"go to google (http://www.google.com)" where as I want to show only 'go to google'

can someone tell me how to fix this,

thanks in advance

cheers,
sameera

Comment: a screenshot would be nice as well the actual html code

Comment: hi 

I fixed the issue with the help of David

I havent use 'media="print"' in the print.css

thanks for the replay

cheers,
sameera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't load `print.css` without specifying `media="print"`

Comment: Hi David Dorward,

thanks man it worked, I didnt use media="print", u saved my day

cheers,
sameera